# What is the difference between 'want camping' and 'I want to camp'?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

I want to learn the difference between 'I want camping' and 'I want to camp'.
Please, somebody tell me the difference~

Comment: "I want camping" doesn't make any sense. It does not mean "I want to camp".

Comment: I can think of contexts in which "I want camping" makes sense.  Please explain your context.

Answer (score 6):

"I want camping" doesn't make sense. "Camping" is an activity, not an object. You can say, "I want to go camping" -- or "I want to camp", your other example. (Similarly, you can't say, "I want eating." You could say "I want to eat" or "I wish I was eating.")

Perhaps you heard or read, "I went camping", that is, "went", not "want". That is a common way of saying that I was camping at some time in the past.

"I want to camp" means that I desire to go camping at some time in the future.

Comment: I was drafting an answer, but yours is just right. +1

Comment: I agree with pretty much everything you said.  Maybe, *maybe*, you could say "I want camping" in the sense of "I desire there to be the activity of 'camping'", but it's really hard to come up with a reasonable use for it.

Comment: @stangdon - +1 for your dual maybes. That said, it's not hard to imagine why an English novice might think "I want camping" is a legitimate way to say "I want to go camping."

Comment: @stangdon Good point. Like, Person A: "What activities should we have for the youth group this year? Boating? Camping? A concert?" Person B: "Oh, I want camping." Unusual, but certainly possible.